# Is there a way to layout my entire level in an .sks file, but only load whats currently in view?

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit

I've seen this concept mentioned around the internet but can't find any specifics on how to do it.

I want to lay out my entire level in an .sks file but load only whats in the view of the player/frame at any given moment. In my game I have platforms that go up and down forever, simple roving enemies, and collectable coins that float in the air while bobbing up and down. Since these actions are using

```
SKAction.repeatForever
```

They are continuously going even when not in view of player. The only other option I see is giving every action a "key" and then placing invisible sprites through out the level that when contacted start and stop certain actions. While doable it seems it could get very convoluted very fast.

Is there a more straightforward way to lay out my entire scene, but only load what's currently in view? I'm not sure what to call this concept which is probably the reason I can't find much on it.

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do it.  My personal method is to load your SKS into an `SKScene` that is not attached to the root node at all (the `SKView`) and use `SKCameraNode`'s `containedNodeSet` to move all nodes from the loaded scene over to the scene that is viewable to the user.  You would then need to implement methods to continuously swap between the two scenes.

If your concern is only actions, then you can avoid the swapping and just pause all nodes not in the `containedNodeSet` and unease the ones that are inside of it.

Comment: Thank you for this! i'll look into containedNodeSet.

Comment: would you be willing to explain the second part you said, about unpausing actions that are only in view?

Comment: start all nodes with isPaused set to true,  then iterate through the containedNodeSet to set isPaused to false.  When a node is no longer in your node set,  set that node back to true.